# SEnse and REmove INstances of 2 CApital LEtters BEginning a WOrd

Tags: autohotkey, writing

Is there an AutoHotkey script that can sense if I accidentally hold down shift too long if I start a word with a capital letter? Microsoft word does this automatically, but I would like it system-wide. The script should be smart enough to tell if I'm typing something in all caps or if I actually made a mistake.

Comment: how would it know the difference between an accidentally capitalized two letter word and an intentionally all caps two letter word?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering about. I don't know.

Comment: @bryan: Two-letter words should just be ignored by the script.  Only 2 capitals followed by at least 1 lowercase should be corrected.  Words that are *supposed to have* 2 capitals and then a lowercase are rare enough that you can make special cases for them.  I have special cases for things like `UPnP` `MWh` `NiCd` `VoIP` `DjVu` `S/PDIF`, etc anyway so that I don't have to wrestle with the Shift key or remember the correct capitalization/punctuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AutoHotkey help file page about "Hotstrings & auto-replace" contains a download link to [AutoCorrect.ahk](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/AutoCorrect.ahk) by [Jim Biancolo](http://www.biancolo.com/articles/universal-autocorrect-with-autohotkey-and-wikipedia) that preforms AutoCorrect features system-wide.

In the script, the correction of two consecutive capitals is commented out by default, but you can remove the `/*` and `*/` lines around it to enable it.

Comment: There are probably better solutions.  This one is `Disabled by default to prevent unwanted corrections such as IfEqual->Ifequal.`  But `IfEqual` is not a double capitalization, so should be ignored by any such script anyway.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly, if user have second keyboard layout. Thanks.